# Mongoid error/conflict with Bundle Install (RoR) using the gem from Github

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

I'm using Ruby 2.0.0 + RoR4.0.2 + Mongoid 4 gem from Github:

Gemfile:

```
gem "moped", github: "mongoid/moped"
gem "mongoid", github: "mongoid/mongoid"
```

The error:

> Git error: command `git clone --no-checkout
>   "/Users/skozz/wwwssd/railsapps/research/vendor/bundle/cache/bundler/git/moped-9b1aedab11453ea81518d1ac845eab1f786d7c14"
>   "/Users/skozz/wwwssd/railsapps/research/vendor/bundle/bundler/gems/moped-a8f96c57042a"`
>   in directory /Users/skozz/wwwssd/railsapps/research has failed. If
>   this error persists you could try removing the cache directory
>   '/Users/skozz/wwwssd/railsapps/research/vendor/bundle/cache/bundler/git/moped-9b1aedab11453ea81518d1ac845eab1f786d7c14'

I can solve the problem removing the cache directory but this problem happens every day and it's bothering me when it happens in production's environment at Heroku.

How I can avoid this conflict automatically?

Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that does not work, you can try this in your Gemfile

gem 'mongoid', :git => 'https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid.git'

That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it specifying the full Github's path

From:

```
gem "moped", github: "mongoid/moped"
gem "mongoid", github: "mongoid/mongoid"
```

To:

```
gem "mongoid",  :git => 'git://github.com/mongoid/mongoid.git'
gem "moped",  :git => 'git://github.com/mongoid/moped.git'
```